# Sticker Book style app to svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a div with relative position and several pngs in it with absolute position and different width/height + rotate values. What I need is to generate svg from it without using any plugin. This is like a sticker book for kids.

Update:

I was able to make a php script to generate the image. But here's the new problem:

Source container width: 700, height: ratio based.
Final container width: 1200, height: ratio based.

Icon 1 from source: width=150px, height=80px, left=30px, top=40px
Icon 2 from source: width=100px, height=100px, left=90px, top=20px
...and so on. About 6-7 stickers at one time with above config.

All the above details are sent to the php script to generate the image. What I need is to calculate the scaling of the icons in the final container using the data above. Not only just width and height but the x and y position also so that the final image looks exactly like the source but just a bigger version.

Appreciate all of your help/comments.

Comment: You should learn about the `viewBox` attribute.  If you make the viewBox the same size as your original parent div, then you can use the same coordinates for the stickers in the SVG that you do in the original background. Then the stickers will automatically scale to whatever scale your SVG is drawn at.  I'm also wondering why you want to use three different representaions of the picture (HTML+CSS,SVG and PNG). Why not just use SVG for the original?

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for the advise. I tried the SVG way but had to go for PHP later on. Because I needed to render the svg to a canvas and then get the base64 encoded string to send to server and save the image as png. When I tried this the custom fonts used in the SVG didn't work on the canvas. I have updated my original post. Would be great if you can have a look. Thanks again.

Comment: Surely it's just: `newX = oldX * (1200/700)` and `newY = oldY * (1200/700)`.

Comment: Thanks, will try this. And how about scaling the width and height of the icons?